# emplace_back() does not behave as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, std

I wrote a simple program to play around with in-place creation of objects inside standard library containers. This is what I wrote:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class AB
{
public:
   explicit AB(int n);
   AB(const AB& other) = delete;
   AB(AB&& other);
   AB& operator=(const AB& other) = delete;
   AB& operator=(AB&& other) = default;
private:
   int i;
};

AB::AB(int n): i( n )
{
   std::cout << "Object created." << std::endl;
};

AB::AB(AB&& other): i( std::move(other.i) )
{
   std::cout << "Object moved." << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector< AB > v;
   v.emplace_back(1);
   v.emplace_back(2);
   v.emplace_back(3);
};
```

I compiled it with g++ (version 4.8.2). After running the output, I got:

```
Object created.
Object created.
Object moved.
Object created.
Object moved.
Object moved.
```

But I expected something like this:

```
Object created.
Object created.
Object created.
```

I thought the whole point of emplacement was to get rid of the movement constructor calls. Are there any requirements in class AB that are not met?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 It is nice to see a question asked clearly, with all the necessary information and a self-contained working code sample. This is, unfortunately, the exception these days.

Comment: Note: if you do not delete the copy constructor, then your object is [copied](http://ideone.com/6yGTEx). This is because unless the Move Constructor is marked `noexcept`, `vector` will prefer to use the non-destructive Copy Constructor instead when re-allocating elements. Therefore... *Do mark the Move Constructor as `noexcept`* :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that your vector is being resized as you add more elements, resulting in extra moves. If you reserve enough capacity at the start, you get the expected result:

```
   std::vector< AB > v;
   v.reserve(3);
   v.emplace_back(1);
   v.emplace_back(2);
   v.emplace_back(3);
```

gives

```
Object created.
Object created.
Object created.
```

On gcc 4.8.2. Note that you can track the vector's growth in your original code by looking at `v.capacity()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been very helpful to my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The point of emplacement is to get rid of the COPY constructor calls. It's probably moving objects around due to resizing the vector when it's full. Moving an object is fine. Copying an object is expensive.